# How to get a pariwise correlation dataframe from a matrix?

Tags: r, matrix, correlation

I have a matrix on which I compute the correlations between my columns. I created a function which gives the result in the form of correlation matrix (because of the `apply()` function), but I would like to get a pairwise correlation dataframe directly.  Is it possible to do that withouth any intermediate matrix : matrix -> pairwise correlation dataframe

```
cor_rho<-function(y) {
res <- foreach(i = seq_len(ncol(y)),
.combine = rbind,
.multicombine = TRUE,
.inorder = FALSE,
.packages = c('data.table', 'doParallel')) %dopar% {
apply(y, 2, function(x) 1 - ((var(y[,i] - x)) / (var(y[,i]) + var(x))))}
return(res)}
```

This is the same function, I just added some lines to get the data.frame I want

```
cor_rho<-function(y) {
res <- foreach(i = seq_len(ncol(y)),
.combine = rbind,
.multicombine = TRUE,
.inorder = FALSE,
.packages = c('data.table', 'doParallel')) %dopar% {
apply(y, 2, function(x) 1 - ((var(y[,i] - x)) / (var(y[,i]) + var(x))))}
colnames(res)=rownames(res)=colnames(y)
Df<-data.frame(var1=rownames(res)[row(res)[upper.tri(res)]],
var2=colnames(res)[col(res)[upper.tri(res)]],
corr=res[upper.tri(res)])
return(Df)}
```

which gives me something like this

```
var1 var2 value
var1 var3 value
var2 var3 value
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use only `dplyr` and `reshape2`, is it working for what you want ?

```
library(reshape2)
library(dplyr)

set.seed(1)
n <- 10
df <- data.frame(var1 = rnorm(n), var2 = rnorm(n), var3 = rnorm(n))
melt(cor(df), id = c("Var1", "Var2")) %>%
  filter(Var1 != Var2) %>%
  filter(duplicated(value))
```

I made an assumption which can be anoying for you, it is to suppose no duplicate between correlation coefficient neither for symetric relation. I hope it will help.

Edit 1 :

I look on internet, I find the following package : `corrr` in which their is a function `correlate` which return you directly a data.frame. If you want the specify output, the following lines gives you something near :

```
install.packages('corrr')
library(corrr)
stretch(correlate(df))
```

But after that you need to do the same trick as above to have only what you want.

Edit 2 :

I look again on internet to see what could help you, in fact the only package which take a matrix in input and gives a data.frame in output is `corrr` but I tested it on a bigger matrix and it is realy slow.

```
n <- 100
p <- 8000
m <- n * p 
df <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(m), nrow = n, ncol = p))


t <- Sys.time()
m_cor <- cor(df)
t <- Sys.time() - t
t1 <- t 

library(corrr)

t <- Sys.time()
m_cor <- correlate(df)
t <- Sys.time() - t
t2 <- t

library(propagate)

t <- Sys.time()
m_cor <- bigcor(df)
t <- Sys.time() - t
t3 <- t
```

Wherease `propogate` seems to be a good thing to deal with very large matrix but I'm not sure to well understand the type `ff` of the output. In my exemple, the basic `cor` function is faster than the two others solution. Do you find any solution ?

I will be happy to see your proposal because it is an interesting question.

Comment: Actually, I would like to know if it possible to get the data.frame directly? I mean, when I compute the correlations on my matrix, I will get a correlation matrix and then, I extract the correlations to make my data.frame. I would like to skip the correlation matrix, and directly get the correlations in the form of data.frame.

Comment: I don't think it exists and in fact the solution above give you what you want in only 3 lines of code. Is it because you have a big dataset ?

Comment: In fact, I work on big data (the matrix I'm working on to make my draft has more than 820k columns..)

Comment: I better understand now, but is the second solution working ?

Comment: Actually, my matrix is too big to work with `propagate` or `corrr` : I get an error message about memory space. So, I have decided to split my matrix into submatrices, I compute the correlations between each of these submatrices (submatrix 1 vs submatrix 2, submatrix 1 vs submatrix 3 , submatrix 2 vs submatrix 3 etc). I will get several submatrices of correlation : I create a pairwise correlation dataframe for each combination. Then, I gather each of these dataframes (I remove the duplicated rows) , and I get my final data.frame which corresponds to my starting matrix.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I think you chose the best solution.